# Placing an image in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css

I want to place a 100px x 100px image in the middle of a 210px width div. Please help. 1em=10px

```css
#sidebox > .centered {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: em;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  margin-top: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0.5em solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-color: #2c3e50;
  background-image: url();
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebox">
  <p>
    <div class="centered"></div>
  </p>
```

Comment: there are many questions like this

Comment: `p` elements can't contain `div` ones.

Comment: Can you set the image as the background image for `#sidebox`, or must it be an image?

Comment: `margin-left: em;` how many em?

Answer (score 1):

You can align your `image <img>` center of `outer div` by below property's

`margin:0 auto;` OR this only works for aligning text or image `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

Might you just need to centre align 100x100px image in 210px width wrapper.
You can centre align [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) using `text-align:center;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebox">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y2IopJORVh4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAD0/ePzQLLN6hKM/photo.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebox{
    width: 210px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #eee;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/4vm74bno/)

Answer (score 0):

The most important point, mentioned by others, is that `text-align:center` must apply to the to the box the image is being centered in, ***not*** the image itself.

You have other problems:

- `position:absolute` will shrink the effective image width to zero ***for centering purposes***, so the left edge will be centered.
- You are using a `<div>` like an `<img>`, but it won't center like an `<img>` unless it is styled with `display:inline-block`.

Before & After:

[image]

Before:

```
    #sidebox { 
      font-size:10px;   /*ADDED so 1em=10px*/
      width: 210px;                 /*ADDED*/
      border: 2px dashed red;       /*ADDED*/ 
    }
    #sidebox > .centered {
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: em;
      height: 10em;
      width: 10em;
      margin-top: 10em;
      position: absolute;
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
      border: 0.5em solid;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border-color: #2c3e50;
      background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y2IopJORVh4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAD0/ePzQLLN6hKM/photo.jpg);
    }

    <div id="sidebox">
      <p>
        <div class="centered"></div>
      </p>
      ***TEXT ADDED***
    </div>
```

After:

```
    #sidebox { 
      font-size:10px;   
      width: 210px;     
      border: 2px dashed red;
      text-align: center;       /*ADDED*/ 
    }
    #sidebox > .centered {
      display:inline-block;     /*ADDED*/
      /*text-align: center;     REMOVED*/
      margin-left: em;
      height: 10em;
      width: 10em;
      margin-top: 10em;
      /*position: absolute;     REMOVED*/
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
      border: 0.5em solid;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border-color: #2c3e50;
      background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y2IopJORVh4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAD0/ePzQLLN6hKM/photo.jpg);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! helped a lot! Mind seeing my other question?